# A word that means "being protected from other people's TMI"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What I mean is the flip side to 'privacy'.
If having your own personal information protected from strangers' eyes is 'privacy', then being protected from unwanted exposure to strangers' secrets, intimate details, nude pics, etc., is...?

Comment: (Self-)Seclusion, perhaps?

Comment: Deaf and blind?

Comment: I will tell you the word for "being protected from other people's TMI" as soon as you tell me the word for "being protected from other people's SWRs".

Comment: @RegDwigнt: sorry, I am not familiar with that abbreviation. Do please enlighten me.

Comment: Why do you assume that we are familiar with yours, then? Anyway, the answer is in the tags you chose, and the thing is, you have to make a rather strong case why you assume such a word exists. Because that is not how language works. Language is not about having a dedicated word for "protected from X" for all values of X. It is about having a few simple words, and combining them in a few simple ways in order to express very complicated things. Like, I dunno, "being protected from other people's TMI".

Comment: Additionally, it should be noted that not only is there no established word, but indeed the concept as such is not established. It is simply not possible to be protected from other people's TMI. By the way, I am posting this naked.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a word that exactly means what you are looking for.  However, I will offer [shielded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shielded), in the "exposed to (danger)" sense of the first verb tense definition given in the link.

Where privacy is a system for preventing things from getting *out*, a shield is a device that prevents things (normally weapons) from getting *in*.  So it works, if perhaps more metaphorically than literally.

Comment: This is definitely too broad. If I told you I am shielded, you'd have no idea what I'm shielded from. It is not a substitute for the phrase "being protected from other people's TMI", but merely one synonym for one word in it.